# lazyppredict - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, automl

I am trying to import a python package called `lazypredict` for my ML project. LazyPredict is an AutoML package

So, I did the below

```py
import lazypredict
from lazypredict.Supervised import REGRESSORS
```

However, there is an error when I execute the 2nd line and the full error message is given below

How can I avoid this and import REGRESSORS module successfully?

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [5], in <cell line: 22>()
     20 from sklearn.ensemble import *
     21 import lazypredict
---> 22 from lazypredict.Supervised import REGRESSORS

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lazypredict\Supervised.py:73, in <module>
     36 removed_classifiers = [
     37     "ClassifierChain",
     38     "ComplementNB",    (...)
     50     "VotingClassifier",
     51 ]
     53 removed_regressors = [
     54     "TheilSenRegressor",
     55     "ARDRegression",     (...)
     68     "VotingRegressor", 
     69 ]
     71 CLASSIFIERS = [
     72     est
---> 73     for est in all_estimators()
     74     if (issubclass(est[1], ClassifierMixin) and (est[0] not in removed_classifiers))
     75 ]
     77 REGRESSORS = [
     78     est
     79     for est in all_estimators()
     80     if (issubclass(est[1], RegressorMixin) and (est[0] not in removed_regressors))
     81 ]
     83 REGRESSORS.append(("XGBRegressor", xgboost.XGBRegressor))

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py:1174, in all_estimators(type_filter)    1151 """Get a list of all estimators from sklearn.    1152     1153 This function crawls the module and gets all classes that inherit    (...)    1171     and ``class`` is the actual type of the class.    1172 """    1173 # lazy import to avoid circular imports from sklearn.base
-> 1174 from ._testing import ignore_warnings    1175 from ..base import (    1176     BaseEstimator,    1177     ClassifierMixin,    (...)    1180     ClusterMixin,    1181 )    1183 def is_abstract(c):

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_testing.py:532, in <module>
    527 skip_travis = pytest.mark.skipif(
    528     os.environ.get("TRAVIS") == "true", reason="skip on travis"
    529 )
    530 fails_if_pypy = pytest.mark.xfail(IS_PYPY, reason="not compatible with PyPy")
    531 fails_if_unstable_openblas = pytest.mark.xfail(
--> 532     _in_unstable_openblas_configuration(),
    533     reason="OpenBLAS is unstable for this configuration",
    534 )
    535 skip_if_no_parallel = pytest.mark.skipif(
    536     not joblib.parallel.mp, reason="joblib is in serial mode"
    537 )
    539 #  Decorator for tests involving both BLAS calls and multiprocessing.
    540 #
    541 #  Under POSIX (e.g. Linux or OSX), using multiprocessing in conjunction    (...)
    555 #  errors on interactively defined functions. It therefore not enabled by
    556 #  default.

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py:93, in
_in_unstable_openblas_configuration()
     90 import numpy  # noqa
     91 import scipy  # noqa
---> 93 modules_info = threadpool_info()
     95 open_blas_used = any(info["internal_api"] == "openblas" for info in modules_info)
     96 if not open_blas_used:

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py:162, in threadpool_info()
    160     return controller.info()
    161 else:
--> 162     return threadpoolctl.threadpool_info()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:124, in threadpool_info()
    107 @_format_docstring(USER_APIS=list(_ALL_USER_APIS),
    108                    INTERNAL_APIS=_ALL_INTERNAL_APIS)
    109 def threadpool_info():
    110     """Return the maximal number of threads for each detected library.
    111 
    112     Return a list with all the supported modules that have been found. Each    (...)
    122     In addition, each module may contain internal_api specific entries.
    123     """
--> 124     return _ThreadpoolInfo(user_api=_ALL_USER_APIS).todicts()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:340, in
_ThreadpoolInfo.__init__(self, user_api, prefixes, modules)
    337     self.user_api = [] if user_api is None else user_api
    339     self.modules = []
--> 340     self._load_modules()
    341     self._warn_if_incompatible_openmp()
    342 else:

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:373, in
_ThreadpoolInfo._load_modules(self)
    371     self._find_modules_with_dyld()
    372 elif sys.platform == "win32":
--> 373     self._find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex()
    374 else:
    375     self._find_modules_with_dl_iterate_phdr()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:485, in
_ThreadpoolInfo._find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex(self)
    482         filepath = buf.value
    484         # Store the module if it is supported and selected
--> 485         self._make_module_from_path(filepath)
    486 finally:
    487     kernel_32.CloseHandle(h_process)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:515, in
_ThreadpoolInfo._make_module_from_path(self, filepath)
    513 if prefix in self.prefixes or user_api in self.user_api:
    514     module_class = globals()[module_class]
--> 515     module = module_class(filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    516     self.modules.append(module)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:606, in
_Module.__init__(self, filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    604 self.internal_api = internal_api
    605 self._dynlib = ctypes.CDLL(filepath, mode=_RTLD_NOLOAD)
--> 606 self.version = self.get_version()
    607 self.num_threads = self.get_num_threads()
    608 self._get_extra_info()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:646, in
_OpenBLASModule.get_version(self)
    643 get_config = getattr(self._dynlib, "openblas_get_config",
    644                      lambda: None)
    645 get_config.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
--> 646 config = get_config().split()
    647 if config[0] == b"OpenBLAS":
    648     return config[1].decode("utf-8")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Would you post your code? Because I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: I mean the above two lines in the post are my code. I got error while importing itself (so didn't write any other code). So, not sure what is the issue. May be some package version conflict? How can I resolve this help please?

Comment: Please add a comment about the result of `pip show lazypredict` in your shell. This will show your package version. If you succeeded in using the package before, you need to remove the current version and install the previous successful version. [the bug report](https://github.com/shankarpandala/lazypredict/issues/391) shows a similar bug in the Windows environment(the pakage version is lazypredict==0.2.12).

Comment: @ConstantinHong - Actually I did use this package before but am not sure what package version was it. I recently updated my numpy and scikit-learn etc and that seemed to have resulted in this issue. Unfortunatelly, I am not a software person to create virtual environment etc. Hence, I was relying on such autoML solutions. but looks autoML solutions still requires lot of software and version mgmt skills. hahah. btw my version is also 0.2.12. Which version did you try to reproduce this error and in which OS?

Comment: I tested on macOS 12.6.1 and RHEL9.0. I imported the package without error. BTW, I suggest removing the current package and installing the previous one. Try `pip uninstall lazypredict` and `pip install lazypredict==0.2.9`. If you still can't import after installation, repeat removing the package and run the install command with other versions (0.2.8, 0.2.7, 0.2.6)

Comment: What does RHEL9.0 mean?

Comment: That is Redhat Linux 9. Unix or Linux system is different from Windows in syntax and the way operates. Because the package runs on other OSs, the error is about compatibility with Windows. In my opinion, you don't have to waste time with the current version of lazypredict. As you said, you successfully ran the program before. So install the previous successful version. Because someone in GitHub already reported the error, you need to wait for the fix. Before the fix release, you have to use the previous successful version.

Comment: None of the previous versions work. Meaning, their installation is hung at the line - `Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... |`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems: (1) Windows 32-bit Python, (2) Missing `OpenBLAS`.

Here are the key parts of the traceback:

```
    372 elif sys.platform == "win32":
--> 373     self._find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex()
------------------------------------------------------------------
    643 get_config = getattr(self._dynlib, "openblas_get_config",
    644                      lambda: None)
    645 get_config.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
--> 646 config = get_config().split()
```

The easiest fix is probably installing [Anaconda or Miniconda on Windows](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html), installing `scipy` and `numpy`, then running `pip install lazypredict`:

```bash
conda install numpy scipy
pip install lazypredict
```